# After installing Android ADT 14: "R cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

After updating to ADT 14, my project which formerly built fine now is full of errors. Everywhere I reference "R" (R.string.mystring, etc.) it says "R cannot be resolved".

I do not have android.R imported anywhere.

There is nothing in my "gen" folder.

"Cleaning" the project just revealed ALL the places I reference "R" by flagging them with an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had something similar after update to R14. This is not a definitive answer, but starting Eclipse with 'eclipse -clean' from the command line APPEARED to fix it. It may have been a coincidence but it's probably worthwhile trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is usually caused by `android.R` being imported, as you state, but since that's not the problem in your case, I'd suspect you've got an XML error in one of your resource files.

Comment: First, they didn't change between the prior version and installing this new one. So unless there was a syntax change, that's not the problem. Second, my XML files do not have any error flags or messages showing anywhere.

Comment: All right, could easily have been the case. XML errors often prevent the "gen" folder from being generated.

Comment: Followed the advice of lukuluku and resinstalled SDK 14 and did another "clean". Now my XML files showed some errors brought on by a stricter interpretation of % in strings. Fixed those and now I'm back online. So it was XML after all, but it just wasn't telling me that.

Comment: Cheers, Eclipse and the SDK can act up a bit from time to time. Just happy you got your issue resolved. I upvoted @lukuluku's answer to give him some credit as well.

Comment: @Michell Bak: thanks. Im glad i could assist in finding a solution

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've installed the latest ADT Eclipse Plug-In or/and reinstall the Android SDK Tools + Platform-Tools from the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" (Eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager)

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above tips, but none of them worked for me. There were no xml errors in my strings file either. Ultimately deleting and recreating the strings.xml was what worked for me.

Comment: oh my ... ! sometimes I just feel like Eclipse was put on earth to annoy the cr*p out of me.. just wasted 2 hours on this. Thank you very much sir

Comment: I feel the same.  I just did an update and have spent hours trying to get back to where I was yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Yes could possibly occur due to R14 and R15, i faced it too, for shortcut solution, try to change any java file, and clean build android project. This created R.java file for me.  I know its not perfect answer for problem, but it works