# Android: What's happening to R library and/or ADT 14 in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I've just installed the SDK and all the stuff necessary for programming Android in  Eclipse for the first time, and I've just find my first problem. After opening a sample project (Snake, for 2.2), there seem to be errors in the code. Well, the R library was not imported. I don't get why it was not already there, but I've imported it. All good? Nope! `text = getString(R.string.tie);`still has an error. Same with the rest of code (when it uses R). `tie` is not recognized, it's not shown in that usual blue of Eclipse.

Eclipse says that the problem is ADT 14... `final` stuff, or `switch` statements. Ok... I've read that. There's no switch there. That's not the problem. Eclipse suggests me to change `.tie` to any other thing... like `button1`. That's not useful, of course. I think the problem is R class, not ADT. Or maybe R class has some `final` statement so it is not accepted.

I've tried to see if it was that and, in opening the R.class, I get this message: "The source attacement does not contain the source for the file R.class." What now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [After installing Android ADT 14: "R cannot be resolved"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906606/after-installing-android-adt-14-r-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Solved... It solves itself when you restart Eclipse. R library doesn't have to be imported. As @pahan says, if it is imported, remove it. And use clean, it works for some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using project-->clean in eclipse. 
if you imported R library remove it. and try again

Comment: if you imported R library remove it. and try again

Answer (score 2):

R is not a library, it is a resources file, which is generated automatically during the build from existing resources. Just make sure that resources are properly placed where they belong. Then build the project and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required package installed in the AVD Manager. Then, check your Problems view in Eclipse and look at all other errors, other then the R-related ones and make sure everything else is fixed first. If you have an error anywhere in your XML layouts for example, R will not generated.